PowerApps information button wider description on DataCard
I have added Information button under the datacard  , but When I click it the size of the description is limited to Datacard size, is there any way to show it wider to show all content ? writing on OnClick or something. The thing is it shows all the content perfectly when I move it to upper sections. But I need to use it under the datacard


One work around could be place the information button outside your data card and align it's X and Y component with you Datacard. Hence it will take as much required place

For scrolling form you can set variable to false when form onvisible
eg: UpdateContext({varIHAPaymentHeight:false})
Then at info button onselect put this:
If(varIHAPaymentHeight=false,UpdateContext({varIHAPaymentHeight:true}),UpdateContext({varIHAPaymentHeight:false}))
Lastly at your datacard height put this:
YourDataCardOriginalHeight + If(varIHAPaymentHeight = true, 150,0)
150 is my info button size when expand
so when you click info button your data card height will auto increase or back to normal

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

If all of the form is visible without scrolling, you could add the text box to the screen instead of inside the data card. Then you can make it as wide as you need it.

There is a scrolling unfortunately . Information button is great to show guides to users about explaining something as a info
